# Qt Designer 5.11.1 doesn't set the font weight to the correct type

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-designer, qt6

I get the following error when I run cmake:

```
C:/Users/Owner/OneDrive/Documents/BJT/src/ui_BJT.h:126:24: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'QFont::Weight' [-fpermissive]
         font.setWeight(75);
                        ^~
In file included from C:/Qt/6.1.2/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:49,
                 from C:/Qt/6.1.2/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:48,
                 from C:/Qt/6.1.2/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets/qcheckbox.h:44,
                 from C:/Qt/6.1.2/mingw81_64/include/QtWidgets/QCheckBox:1,
                 from C:/Users/Owner/OneDrive/Documents/BJT/src/ui_BJT.h:14,
                 from C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\Documents\BJT\src\ui_BJT.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/6.1.2/mingw81_64/include/QtGui/qfont.h:200:27: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void QFont::setWeight(QFont::Weight)'
     void setWeight(Weight weight);
                    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

The offending code is here:

```
QFont font;
font.setFamily(QStringLiteral("Times New Roman"));
font.setPointSize(16);
font.setBold(true);
font.setWeight(75);
titleLabel->setFont(font);
```

The workaround is to change font.setWeight(75); to font.setWeight(QFont::Weight(75)); which I can easily do.  However, this is generated code, which shouldn't be changed.  Is this a bug is Qt Designer?  Is there something I can do in Qt Designer to remedy this (maybe with style sheets)?  Is this fixed in a later version of Qt Designer?

Comment: You say Qt 5.11.1,  but the error shows Qt 6.1.2. Are you linking / including the right version?

Comment: Qt6 changes the type of the argument for `setWeight`. Now it is **enumeration** [QFont::Weight](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfont.html#Weight-enum), and it uses **new scale** 100-900 instead of 0-87 in [old version](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#Weight-enum). Old type of the argument - int - is accessible via **legacy** method [setLegacyWeight](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfont-obsolete.html#setLegacyWeight).